# How can I prevent CRA's bundler from creating files with a leading dot?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using Create react app for my project (referred to as CRA throughout this post)
I'm importing a 3rd party text editor in my project, which also requires me to import styles like so:

```
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/styles/material.css';
```

One of those files imports a font (used to style the various buttons).
When I build the app, CRA's bundler minifies all assets and creates randomly looking file names for them, like so:

```
.c5f6158ac1190f9247b0
```

Now for the issue:

This works perfectly well on my Windows machine's local server, however when deploying on a Linux server trying to get that file returns a 404.

I found out that the issue is caused by Linux treating all files starting with a leading dot as hidden files, which by default are not accessible.

Is there a way to configure the bundler to not create leading dot filenames? I also have CRACO set up on the project if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the webpack.configure object in craco. This removes any dots before or after the hash, but I'm guessing it could become a problem if loading other different file types (my file was generated from webpack and had no actual name or extension)

```
  config.output.assetModuleFilename = 'static/media/[name][hash:8][ext]';
```